# Selenium: testing django form, file not upload

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have a form similar to django admin form, where user can create object and attach related models to it using separate forms in popup windows.

In my form user can attach file to model. They clicks in plus button...

[image]

and such popup form shows up: 
[image]

After file upload and submit form, new file is created and displayed in select input:
[image]

Now, I want to test this behaviour using selenium. However, when popup closes after form submit, select input is still empty.

This is how I attach file in my test:

```
# select plus btn
plus_btn = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    ".related-widget-wrapper select#id_files + a")

plus_btn.click()

self.switch_to_popup()

file_input = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "input[name='_file']")

file_input.send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/test.txt")

self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "input[type='submit']").click()

self.switch_to_main()
```

PS:
The problem is not in *self.switch_to_popup* and *self.switch_to_main*. These are valid, working methods created by me.

Comment: Check whether there is only one input field: `print(len(self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(    "input[name='_file']")))`

Comment: File upload is a bit tricky in selenium. using send_keys is one way an also try using robot framework or try simulating OS's keyboard controls. Try recording selenium IDE/Builder to see how selenium is dealing with it.

Comment: I just checked, there is only one input field.

Comment: What debugging have you done and what did you find? Put a breakpoint on the submit click line and run the script. Once it breaks, wait a bit... does the file name show up correctly? If so, it's likely a timing issue and you'll have to do some waiting.

Comment: See if Developer tools consoles show an issues or errors when Selenium browser submits. It might be something related to page

Answer (score 0):

Selenium works asynchronously, so after a click or other event happens, your testing code might check the contents of a field a tiny fraction of a second before the field has updated itself. What I do is I wait for a field to contain a value, like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(locator, 'This is test file'))
```

Comment: I hope I understand your answer: I added time.sleep(10) after **self.switch_to_main()** where I look for file name in select input + after **file_input.send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/test.txt")** just in case. But it changed nothing. Still select element is empty after popup close.